# how to use angular's route and django'url?

Tags: django

how to combine `angular-route` and `django's url`
somebody say don't use django's `template` and `url`
just use django for `API`
how can I mutual butween django and angularJS?

Comment: Did you check these links https://coderwall.com/p/8xu-7q/getting-django-url-patterns-to-play-nicely-with-angular-s-routeprovider & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18895290/angularjs-routing-with-djangos-urls